# error: suspicious ownership or permission with nix-shell command on plutus-apps repository

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix, docker

Using the `nix-shell` command in a docker container on GitHub codespaces results in the following error:

```
$ nix-shell --show-trace
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for cabal-install entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
building '/nix/store/q6yfjd9rgb49g5g89x9gqlsv9sv8rs2g-cabal.project.drv'...
error: suspicious ownership or permission on '/nix/store/lzcnjxp2ri40gfy0yysww2vpiac4sng0-cabal.project' for output 'out'; rejecting this build output
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/5hyxv4yfwk8a1jml1cs2yifkxncym1sd-cabal-install-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/gp4k8l89l05jh9a62i6ahdy8h3gfpkng-cabal-install-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed to build

       … while importing '/nix/store/2wiwkbq968s4l3mg9mal28sxfbsy2xm5-cabal-install-plan-to-nix-pkgs'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/import-and-filter-project.nix:21:13:

           20|   projectSubDir'' = if projectSubDir == "" then "" else projectSubDir + "/"; # With trailing /
           21|   project = import "${projectNix}${projectSubDir'}";
             |             ^
           22| in project // {

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/lib/import-and-filter-project.nix:5:1:

            4| { pkgs, haskellLib }:
            5| { projectNix, sourceRepos, src }:
             | ^
            6| let

       … from call site

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:488:27:

          487|               callProjectResults = callCabalProjectToNix args;
          488|               plan-pkgs = importAndFilterProject {
             |                           ^
          489|                 inherit (callProjectResults) projectNix sourceRepos src;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:510:43:

          509|               project = addProjectAndPackageAttrs rec {
          510|                   inherit (pkg-set.config) hsPkgs;
             |                                           ^
          511|                   inherit pkg-set;

       … while evaluating the attribute 'hsPkgs'

       at /nix/store/8n76c1c3nz2wl6dzxmxdz2y5xrx70flw-source/overlays/haskell.nix:533:15:

          532|               # Haskell packages
          533|               hsPkgs = final.lib.mapAttrs (packageName: package':
             |               ^
          534|                 if package' == null

       … while evaluating the attribute 'extraPackages.cabal-install.components.exes.cabal'

       at /workspaces/ppp-3/plutus-apps/nix/pkgs/haskell/extra.nix:73:39:

           72|   inherit (hlsProject.hsPkgs) haskell-language-server hie-bios implicit-hie stylish-haskell hlint;
           73|   inherit (cabalInstallProject.hsPkgs) cabal-install;
             |                                       ^
           74|   inherit (cardanoRepoToolProject.hsPkgs) cardano-repo-tool;

       … while evaluating anonymous lambda

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:145:17:

          144|           (map (drv: drv.__spliced.buildBuild or drv) depsBuildBuild)
          145|           (map (drv: drv.nativeDrv or drv) nativeBuildInputs
             |                 ^
          146|              ++ lib.optional separateDebugInfo' ../../build-support/setup-hooks/separate-debug-info.sh

       … from call site

       … while evaluating 'getOutput'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/lib/attrsets.nix:486:23:

          485|   */
          486|   getOutput = output: pkg:
             |                       ^
          487|     if pkg.outputUnspecified or false

       … from call site

       … while evaluating the attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of the derivation 'ghc-shell-for-packages'

       at /nix/store/kawxd91ly09hlyqprqs7yn650s3cfvf6-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:203:11:

          202|         // (lib.optionalAttrs (attrs ? name || (attrs ? pname && attrs ? version)) {
          203|           name =
             |           ^
          204|             let
```

I was following this [guide](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program) "Enter a `nix-shell`"

Nix version 2.5.1

Nix installation for single user

Comment: Is this better addressed in: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/issues

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your `/nix/store` is somehow corrupted. Without having it hand it's hard to tell what exactly went wrong. You can try:

```
nix-collect-garbage
nix-shell
```

hopefully the bad path would be collected and refetched/built.

Comment: Thanks @angerman, I did what you told me, but it resulted in the same error